# Install libgdm amd64 along side arm64, Ubuntu x86_64 emulation, Parallels, Apple Silicon chip

Tags: apt, package-management, arm64, parallels

I have Parallels Desktop with Ubuntu 20.04.2 (x86_64 emulation). It runs on macOS Apple Silicon chip. Parallels makes native arm64 Ubuntu to run amd64 binaries using Rosetta. I'm trying to install Unity Hub which is amd64 only. It downloaded the most of amd64 dependencies but some of them are not installed automatically (I think because they are system default and not listed). For example I installed manually libdrm2:amd64 successfully along side native one. But the next dependency I'm trying to resolve is libgdm.so.1 which is the part of the package libgdm1. When I made `sudo apt install libgdm1:amd64` I lost GUI. I reinstalled Ubuntu and found that this command is going to remove native arm64 gdm3. Is it possible to install amd64 version and keep native arm64 version?

Here is the output of the command:

```
parallels@ubuntu-linux-22-04-02-desktop:~$ sudo apt install libgdm1:amd64
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  gir1.2-accountsservice-1.0 gir1.2-adw-1 gir1.2-gck-1 gir1.2-gcr-3 gir1.2-geoclue-2.0 gir1.2-gnomebluetooth-3.0 gir1.2-graphene-1.0 gir1.2-gtk-4.0
  gir1.2-gweather-3.0 gir1.2-json-1.0 gir1.2-mutter-10 gir1.2-nm-1.0 gir1.2-nma-1.0 gir1.2-rsvg-2.0 gir1.2-upowerglib-1.0 gnome-bluetooth-3-common
  gnome-shell-common gstreamer1.0-pipewire libgnome-bluetooth-3.0-13 libsysmetrics1 switcheroo-control xwayland
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  dconf-gsettings-backend:amd64 libdconf1:amd64 notification-daemon policykit-1-gnome
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  gdm3 gir1.2-gdm-1.0 gnome-initial-setup gnome-shell gnome-shell-extension-appindicator gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons-ng
  gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock libgdm1 ubuntu-desktop ubuntu-desktop-minimal ubuntu-session
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  dconf-gsettings-backend:amd64 libdconf1:amd64 libgdm1:amd64 notification-daemon policykit-1-gnome
0 upgraded, 5 newly installed, 11 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 206 kB of archives.
After this operation, 8558 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] n
Abort.
```

[A link to an article regarding Rosetta in Parallels Desktop](https://kb.parallels.com/en/129871)

Comment: Some packages simply occupy the same locations in the filesystem even in different architectures, so they can't be installed together. Is just installing the x86-64 version of Ubuntu not an option if you're relying on Rosetta anyway?